# How to reverse a linked list without changing the original one in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to test if a linked list is palindrome. To do this, I'm just going to reverse the linked list, and then check each node one by one in a loop. However, I don't know how to pass the original linked list by value. I think right now I'm passing the linked list by its reference, which modified the original structure after I reverse it.

```
 /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* reverseList(ListNode* head) {
        if(!head) return NULL;

        ListNode* current = head;
        ListNode* pre = NULL;
        ListNode* nextTemp = NULL;

        while(current!=NULL) {
            nextTemp = current->next;
            current->next = pre;
            pre = current;
            current = nextTemp;
        }
        head = pre;
        return head;
    }
    bool isPalindrome(ListNode* head) {
        ListNode* original = head;
        ListNode* reverse = reverseList(head);// is there a way that I can pass it as a copy?

        while(original!=NULL){
            if(reverse->val == original->val){
                reverse=reverse->next;
                original=original->next;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;

    }
};
```

Comment: Instead of making copies, why not just undo the reverse operation at the end?

Comment: @EvanWeissburg you will compare the reversed list with... what?

Comment: If this is a school assignment: You want a LinkedList class separate from and in addition to your ListNode class. You want LinkedList to have a *copy constructor*. If this is anything else: never use a linked list, much less your own linked list.

Comment: You can store every value in a vector, then it's easy to go both ways (or use [std::equal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
ListNode* original = head;
```

Your just copying the pointer which means you have two pointer variable pointing to the same area of memory so changing one will change the other. Could you not just de-reference the pointer and make a copy of that. You could then get a pointer to that new variable if need be.

```
ListNode original = *head;
ListNode* original2 = &original;
```

You can then modify original2 without changing the head.

Comment: This looks dangerous - the first node will stay the same, but "reversing original2" will modify its successor to precede the copied head, making the original list a strange three element list with the last element a copy of the first but for the member `next`.